# How do I earn the "So much room!" achievement in Game Corp DX?

Tags: game-corp

The build area in [Game Corp DX](http://www.gamecorpdx.com/) seems to be static based on the city, yet there's an achievement for "expanding" it.

[image: So much room!]

How do I earn this achievement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly quote the developer of the game:

"You can extend the build area with $100M, check the Studio Info Window. Cheers!"

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that window.  Thanks for your help!